# Cannot Use Float in BMI Calculator

Tags: python, function

I've built the following code:

```
# function to calculate bmi and return a result based on user input

def calculatebmi(weight, height):
    bmivalue = weight // (height ** 2)
    if bmivalue < 18.5:
        print("Underweight "), print(bmivalue)
    elif bmivalue >= 18.5 and bmivalue <= 24.9:
        print("Healthy "), print(bmivalue)
    elif bmivalue <= 25.0 and bmivalue >= 29.9:
        print("Overweight "), print(bmivalue)
    elif bmivalue >= 30.0:
        print("Obese "), print(bmivalue)


# establish usable variables based on user input

user_weight_kg1, user_height_m1 = input("What is your weight in kilograms? "), input("What is your height in meters? ")

# convert user input to float

user_weight_kg2, user_height_m2 = float(user_weight_kg1), float(user_height_m1)

# run the function

calculatebmi(user_weight_kg2, user_height_m2)
```

For whatever reason, when I input "75" for the weight value and "1.7" for the height value, it simply returns:

```
What is your weight in kilograms? 75
What is your height in meters? 1.7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I use integers, it works fine:

```
What is your weight in kilograms? 80
What is your height in meters? 2
Healthy 
20.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I need to be able to have my users input a string and then convert it to a float afterwards. What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate the help!

Comment: `bmivalue <= 25.0 and bmivalue >= 29.9` will never be true. Additionally, what happens if `bmivalue` is 24.95?

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid integer division at the `bmivalue` calculation

```
bmivalue =  weight / (height ** 2)
```

instead of

```
bmivalue = weight // (height ** 2)
```

And make sure to correct the statement at

```
elif bmivalue <= 25.0 and bmivalue >= 29.9:
```

change to

```
elif (bmivalue >= 25.0) and (bmivalue <= 29.9):
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try that and got the same results, wherein the float 1.7 seems to not produce a result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains unnecessary and repeated comparisons. It also doesn't contain any kind of validation. Try this (output modified):

```
def get_bmi(weight, height):
    try:
        if (BMI := float(weight) / (float(height) ** 2)) < 18.5:
            c = 'Underweight'
        elif BMI < 25.0:
            c = 'Healthy'
        elif BMI < 30.0:
            c = 'Overweight'
        else:
            c = 'Obese'
        return f'{BMI=:.1f} -> {c}'
    except ValueError as e:
        return str(e)

weight = input('Input weight in kg: ')
height = input('Input your height in metres: ')

print(get_bmi(weight, height))
```

**Example:**

```
Input weight in kg: 72
Input height in metres: 1.8
BMI=22.2 -> Healthy
```